# Chrome and file system objects

Tags: file, google-chrome, object, asp-classic, system

I have been doing a lot of research and trying to find a work around for a problem I have.

I am working with old code. Classic ASP with VBscript. 
The tool we have working is file system objects. A user uploads a file into the input and it then gets added to the companies fileshare file. The problem is that google chrome has decided to not support VBscript. I easily converted the VBscript to Javascript using activeX but that is basically IE. We got it working in chrome using the plugin IE tabs. But we do not want to use the plug in.

My question is, since javascript is read only and we are running classic asp as our server side language is there any way that we can implement a cross browser file upload?

Comment: *"but that is basically IE"*, *"Javascript is read-only"*, What??

Comment: ActiveX is for internet explorer. Not supported by chrome. Javascript is read only due to security risk on the client side. If I want to write to a file I need node.js, which is not an option here. I am trying jquery with ajax right now.

Comment: That wasn't my point, my point is why are you using an ActiveX control to convert the vbscript to javascript? Plus javascript is not read only there's too much generalisation in the question. All in all not a good fit for SO. Let's face it file upload is bread and butter for any web dev, you're not limited to node.js thats just nonsense.

Comment: I was asked to do this for my boss. I am a front end guy and never really did much back end stuff. I had VBscript which is not supported by chrome. My boss not knowing that told me to convert the VB to JS using activeX. Since that doesnt work with chrome he told me to figure something else out. I am now working with a form that sends the form data to a asp page and handles it there. So I am figuring it out now and I will post back to here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting ActiveX vbscript to javascript to run in crhome will not work.  The reason for this is browsers have a security sandbox which prevents access to the filesystem.  If the file share is on the same server as the web server, you would have to process the file uploads server side through a backend language like asp, asp.net, php.

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up having to do. It was a good learning curve. Now I know a bunch of ways of how not to do it as well lol. I ended up getting it to work and do what I need in asp. Thank you!